# jQuery Mobile $("#popup").popup("open"); not working after transitioning pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have 2 JQM pages and 1 popup  that they both share.  I have an event handler bound to the "pagecreate" of both with code like this inside:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function() {
    $("#cart-button").on("tap", function(event) {
        alert("home alerted");
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#cartContextMenu").popup("open", { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY });
    });
});

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#cat-cart", function() {
    $("#cart-button").on("tap", function(event) {
        alert("cat cart alerted");
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#cartContextMenu").popup("open", { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY });
    });
});
```

HTML Popup code inside BOTH pages JQM page tag:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="cartContextMenu" data-arrow="true">
    <a href="#cat-cart"><input class="create-a-new-order" data-icon="plus" type="button" value="Create Order" /></a>
    <a href="#cat-cart"><input data-icon="forward" type="button" value="4398230424" /></a>
    <a href="#cat-cart"><input data-icon="forward" type="button" value="4398230324" /></a>
    <a href="#cat-cart"><input data-icon="forward" type="button" value="CSOS8230948" /></a>
    <a href="#cat-cart"><input data-icon="forward" type="button" value="44948" /></a>
    <a href="#cat-cart"><input data-icon="forward" type="button" value="CFDXKJFJF" /></a>
</div>
```

When I click/tap the button on the #home page the popup shows fine... when I transition to #cat-cart and click the button again, the alert fires, but the JQM popup is not shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple, each time tap event is bound to the first button occurrence, which is page 1.

Have a different button on each page.

Comment: I wish this was the answer... when I removed the event handler for #home it still wouldn't work on #cat-cart

Comment: Ok, then lets us think out of the box. Are you using multi-page template where all pages are part of a single HTML file? Or are you using multi HTML template where each HTML file holds one jQM page?

Comment: I will create you a working example, give me few minutes

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/87jLjqv0/ In this case we are using delegated event binding, basically we don't care if element is part of the DOM. But once it's there this binding will kick in. Simply change pages and see how everything works.

Comment: Even in your JS Fiddle Example, I'm getting: Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
 

throw new Error( msg );

Comment: I forgot that popup is on the same level as rest of the pages: http://jsfiddle.net/qy10y5bg/

Comment: In your second fiddle I am getting: `Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
 

throw new Error( msg );`

Comment: `.enhanceWithin()` was the answer. I ended up moving the code to `(document).ready(function() {` like this: `$("#cartContextMenu").enhanceWithin().popup();
 
 $(document).on("tap", "#cart-button", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#cartContextMenu").popup("open", { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY });
 });`

Comment: One other thing to note is when you use `enchanceWithin()` you need to manually define the `data-theme` tag or else JQM will enhance the element without any theme (in this case transparent!)